# Setting UITextView height to a variable number of lines

Tags: ios, uitextview

I have a a `UITextView`  populated with a paragraph of text with variable height at runtime.

At runtime, how do I adjust the height of `UITextView` to the height of a variable number of lines (not necessarily equal to the number lines in the paragraph of text)?

For example:

- Set `UITextView` to the height of 2 lines of text for some cases of text, then
- Set `UITextView` to the height of 5 lines of text for other cases of text (with a scroll-bar to scroll for the other lines as is default behavior)

The analogue in CSS would be to set the view height to `2em` if the text is "small", or to `5em` if the text is "large", or in Android setting `maxLines` on a `TextView` at runtime.

Comment: Using autolayout, as per text, you can use different value for height constraint

Comment: @Dili I can't use a preset height as the amount of text changes at runtime, rather I want a height based on the # of lines. E.g. only show 2 lines for some text, or only show 5 lines of text before the scrollbar. (updated Q to make this more clear)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use autolayout. first you create a height constraint for your UITextView. then you outlet this constraint to your controller. then you can manipulate height from controller anytime you like.

```
 @IBOutlet weak var heightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        heightConstraint.constant = 200 // or something else

    }
```

[image: viewcontroller]